# How to know if a device comes into my WiFi network range even though it does not connect to my network

Tags: network, wifi

How to know if a device comes into my WiFi network range even though it does not connect to my network?

Here my business model is that when someone comes into my Wi-Fi range if I can know the count of it for suppose I run a restaurant every time I cannot be there but when I can know the count of the people, then I can say these many people come to my restaurant in this particular time and I can provide analytics for every 1hr or 10 min. Then I can know the people I need to keep for work at my restaurant at that particular time. This is simply my intention. Here generally WiFi is turned on the everyone's mobile.

Comment: I don't see how this question is relevant to information security, since no information seem to be at risk here. Therefore I propose to close it as off-topic.

Comment: Do you want to stalk/surveil someone? That is so off-topic here

Comment: Here my business model is that when someone comes into my Wi-Fi range if I can know the count of it (suppose I run a restaurant every time I cannot be there but when I can know the count of the people then I can say these many people come to my restaurant in this particular time.) I can provide analytics for every 1hr or 10 min. Then I can know my people I need to keep for work at my restaurant in that particular time.

Comment: Then this isn't a security matter

Comment: Count of WiFi-capable devices and count of people are not equal!  Video processing on a camera feed is going to give much higher quality count of customers entering and leaving.

Answer (score 0):

If you know John's MAC address then you can put your wireless card into monitor mode and listen for any packets which have that MAC as the source.

But MAC addresses are trivial to spoof, and some systems automatically randomise the MAC address to try and prevent exactly this kind of thing - so it's not going to be very reliable.